# ANTLR4: Two channels, one for CSV-formatted data, one for key/value-formatted data -- does not work

Tags: parsing, csv, antlr, antlr4, lexical-analysis

The lexer grammar below contains two sets of rules: (1) rules for tokenizing CSV-formatted input, and (2) rules for tokenizing key/value-formatted input. For (1) I put the tokens on channel(0). For (2) I put the tokens on channel(1). Do you see any problems with my lexer grammar?

Also below is a parser grammar and it also contains two sets of rules: (1) rules for structuring CSV tokens into a parse tree, and (2) rules for for structuring key/value tokens into a parse tree. Do you see any problems with my parser grammar?

When I apply ANTLR to the grammar files, compile, and then run the test rig (with the -gui flag) using this CSV input:

```
FirstName, LastName, Street, City, State, ZipCode
Mark,, 4460 Stuart Street, Marion Center, PA, 15759
```

the parse tree is completely wrong - the tree contains no data. I have no idea why the parse tree is wrong. Any suggestions? I have tested each part separately (removed the key/value rules from the lexer and parser grammars and ran it with CSV input, removed the CSV rules from the lexer and parser grammars and ran it with key/value input) and it works fine.

**Lexer Grammar**

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;      

COMMA  : ','            -> channel(0) ;
NL     : ('\r')?'\n'    -> channel(0) ;
WS     : [ \t\r\n]+     -> skip, channel(0) ;
STRING : (~[,\r\n])+     -> channel(0) ;            

KEY       : ('FirstName' | 'LastName')  -> channel(1) ;
EQ        : '='                         -> channel(1) ;
NL2       : ('\r')?'\n'                 -> channel(1) ;
WS2       : [ \t\r\n]+                  -> skip, channel(1) ;
VALUE     : (~[=\r\n])+                  -> channel(1) ;
```

**Parser Grammar**

```
parser grammar MyParser;                

options { tokenVocab=MyLexer; }         

csv       : (header rows)+ EOF ;
header    : field (COMMA field)* NL ;
rows      : (row)* ;    
row       : field (COMMA field)* NL ;
field     : STRING | ;

keyValue  : pairs EOF ;
pairs     : (pair)+ ;
pair      : key EQ value NL2;
key       : KEY ;
value     : VALUE ;
```

Comment: Why are you using channels in lexer grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longest token match wins and if two matches are equal-sized the first one matches. That means:

`STRING` subsumes `KEY`, `EQ` and `VALUE`, you will never get Tokens of the latter types.

The ANTLR parser needs random Access on the token stream, thus not allowing context sensitive lexing.

I suggest to put both lexer grammars into separate grammars. Maybe it gets tricky to use them with a common parser grammar. If so - split the parser grammar as well.